# Cordova Ionic TCP Raw Socket Protocol examples

Tags: cordova, sockets, tcp, ionic-framework

I am trying to use a hybrid phone app solution using ionic and cordova. The big challenge i am facing is with a basic connection to the raw socket that i need to make. Can you please point out to a good implementation of raw socket connection via ionic and some code base - pointers on how to achieve it. I found very less information on this on the internet that i could consume easily.

Comment: Did you find any?

Comment: Please, have you found a solution for this?